# Integer.decode() Java / C#

Tags: java, c#

This line of code is written in java:

```
c = (char) ( (Integer.decode(thisElement).intValue() & 0xFF00) >> 8 );
```

To convert it to C#, I could find `Convert.ToInt32` C# equivalent for the `Integer.decode`

but I do not have any idea how to convert `intValue()` in this code.

this is what I have done in C#:

```
 c = (char) ( (Convert.ToInt32(thisElement). intValue()  & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove `.intValue()` and see if that works

Comment: What makes you think you *need* an equivalent of `intValue()` in C#? Are you sure that `Convert.ToInt32` will actually do what you want? What is your input, and what do you want your output to be? Just transliterating code from one language to another is a bad idea, generally...

Comment: Have you tried casting it to int? I mean Convert.ToInt32((int)thisElement)

Comment: I do not get any error in that case but it is really the correct way?

Comment: `I do not get any error` Are you sure? your code won't compile when you have `.intValue()` .

Comment: I can not compile the code now because some other parts is needed to be converted to C# --but I do not get error when I remove intValue() part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  c = (Char) ((Convert.ToInt32(thisElement) & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

`Convert.ToInt32` returns `int` (as you can see from method's name) so you can immediately do bitwise operations like `&` and `>>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java well enough to know if this is right, but it compiles as C#, and does *something*.

```
c = (char)((byte)((int.Parse(thisElement) & 0xFF00) >> 8));
```

Comment: `(byte)` is incorrect in the code: you're narrowing the answer down to 0..255 range when char is of 0..65535 range

Comment: Is the Java char 8 bits, or 16?  I don't honestly know.  either way, the `& 0xFF00` followed by `>> 8` pretty much guarantees an 8-bit answer anyway... right?

Comment: Java char (like C# one) is 16 bit; ">> 8" is just a shift and it alone guarantees 24-bit answer (int32 = 32 bit - 8 bit for shift = 24 bit). However, the combination of "& 0xFF00" and ">> 8" yes, in fact, guarantee 8-bit answer.